# Common datatrigger in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any way to make this common?

```
<Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentEnum}"
                   Value="{x:Static Enum.Smth}">
              <Setter Property="Header"
                      Value="Other header" />
      </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Or

```
<Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentEnum}"
                       Value="{x:Static Enum.Smth}">
                  <Setter Property="Content"
                          Value="Other title" />
          </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Would be great if there is some way to pass parameter like "Title" to trigger and use it on every framework element.

I tried to make attached properties:

```
behaviors:ChangeContentOnCondition.ContentToChange="NewHello"
behaviors:ChangeContentOnCondition.DefaultContent="Hello"
behaviors:ChangeContentOnCondition.ChangeWhenObjectEqualsTo="{x:Static Enum.Smth}"
behaviors:ChangeContentOnCondition.Value="{Binding CurrentEnum}"
```

This failed when i didnt know how to listen when all properties are set.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find this easier if you create a single Behavior, with all of the attached properties contained within the Behavior class. This will allow you to change the necessary property.

Also, for the "ContentToChange", I'd set the value using a Binding rather than a string value to avoid you having to try to do a property lookup on the Attached object.

Comment: I made smth like behavior and its called "ChangeContentOnCondition" but i have all static properties. So when i attach this behavior to another control properties are mixing around. For example i have label and set this behavior to label is ok, but if i add this to next for example tabitem i have set title on this tabitem from label.

Comment: Don't use static properties then. That's what will happen. Use attached properties.